# Qt forward slot / connect slot to slot?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I came into situation where I have to call object's slot after receive signal (just forward the signal to the other's object slot). I know I can simply implement slot and call another slot from the body, but maybe I can do it in more simple way?

Here's sample code:

```
class SomeWidget : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    textChanged(QString);
    //...
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class SomeController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    processText(QString);
    //...

public:
    SomeController()
    {
        connect(this, &SomeController::processText, &someUtil, &SomeUtil::processText);
        //^^ this won't work, linker can not find SomeController::processText
    }
private:
    SomeUtil someUtil; //doesn't matter, just does something
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

//code somewhere else
connect (someWidget, &SomeWidget::textChanged, someController, &SomeController::processText)
```

**EDIT:**

OK, maybe my question is not clear enough - concidering my example - I don't want to connect directly `SomeWidget` with `SomeUtil` as I want to hide fact that I even use `SomeUtil`. This class should be invisible for `SomeController`'s user. It's a matter of encapsulation. `SomeController` is kind of facade.

What is more I don't need to implement `SomeController`'s slot. It's only work is to call `SomeUtil`'s slot (forward the signal).

Comment: you can declare signal in your SomeController class, connect signals to each other and when widget will emit textChanged signal - your controller will emit processText signal too

Comment: @ctinka indeed I can but I wouldn't consider this as a nice solution. Signals are considered to be function which "speaks", not "listens".

Comment: in Qt library it ok to connect a signal to another one

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the signal to both slots and they will both be called, in the order you connect them.

Answer (score 0):

1. answering your question: you can make two connections one-by-one and slots will be called in the same sequence
   something like

   ```
   connect(someWidget, &SomeWidget::textChanged, someController, &SomeController::processText);
   connect(someWidget, &SomeWidget::textChanged, anotherController, &SomeController::processText);
   ```

this is useful if you need to call multiple slots:

```
connect(someWidget, &SomeWidget::textChanged, someController, &SomeController::processText);
connect(someWidget, &SomeWidget::textChanged, someController, &SomeController::update);
```

but if you need to call private member function of the same class - you need to make wrapper slot:

```
class SomeController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void processText(QString);
    {
        foo();
        bar();
    }
private:
    void foo();
    void bar();
};
```

2. in your code you connecting to the processText signal, but your class SomeController doesn't have any signals

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ctinka, defining `SomeController::processText` as a signal is the right solution.

It is explicitly stated in the [Qt Signals & Slots documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots) that you may connect a signal to another signal:

> It is even possible to connect a signal directly to another signal.
>   (This will emit the second signal immediately whenever the first is
>   emitted.)

**Further considerations**

Note that slots are normal C++ functions, so Qt is not able to perform any special logic (like calling the connected slots):

> Slots are normal C++ functions and can be called normally; their only
>   special feature is that signals can be connected to them.

On the other hand, signals are generated by Qt (`moc`) and therefore are able to call connected slots:

> Signals are automatically generated by the moc and must not be
>   implemented in the .cpp file.